# Dynamically load a subset of React components from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I have a React component, ItemsContainer, that I want to render a group of Items within (each in a new row). ItemsContainer receives two props, `items` which is an array of the Item components it should render, and `numberOfItems` which is a number signaling how many items I want rendered at a time. Each item has a dismiss button that should make the current item disappear and cause the other items in the container to move up, and the next item in `items` to appear (same flow as dismissing notifications on a social media site). I’m having trouble figuring out:
1. How to only render `numberOfItems` `Items` at a time
2. How to make an item disappear when it is clicked and the next item to appear, without triggering a re-render of the other items

I was using Array.map to render the items, but this renders all the items at a time when I only want to be rendering a certain subset of them, and then also trying to figure out the logic of how to handle dismissals.

Comment: could we see what you've tried

Comment: you can use filter then map the result if you use a library like lodash _.chain(array).filter(item => condition === true).map(item => yo shit).value()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get the items that haven't been dismissed and then apply `splice` to the remaining items to limit how many are rendered:

```js
const items = [{ id: 0, message: 'Test 1'},{ id: 1, message: 'Test 2'},{ id: 2, message: 'Test 3'},{ id: 3, message: 'Test 4'},{ id: 4, message: 'Test 5'},{ id: 5, message: 'Test 6'}]

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    notifications: items,
    displayAmt: 2
  };

  renderNotifications = () => {
    const { notifications, displayAmt } = this.state;
    
    // First, filter out all notifications that have been dismissed
    // Then, splice the remaining items to only get n amount at a time
    // Last, map over the remaining items and render them
    return notifications.filter( notification => !notification.dismissed )
      .splice(0, displayAmt)
      .map( notification => (
        <li onClick={() => this.dismissNotification(notification.id)} key={notification.id}>  
          {notification.message}
        </li>
      ));
    
  };
  
  dismissNotification = id => {
  
    // Use the id passed in to update the item in state from dismissed: false -> true
    const notifications = this.state.notifications.map( notification => {
      if(notification.id === id) {
        notification.dismissed = true;
      }
      return notification;
    });
    this.setState({ notifications });
  };

  render() {
    const notifications = this.renderNotifications();
    return (
      <ul>
        {notifications}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chase, this is extremely helpful. My one question is, won't this end up rerendering all child components (each `Item`) every time a notification is dismissed? Is there a way to only render the new child component that's being created, and have the existing two or three on the page be the same components?

Comment: Well that's how React works, it "renders" everything again. The magic is that it uses an elements `key` to determine if it actually needs to be re-rendered. If nothing has changed, it won't re-render it. So even though we are sending a "new" list of items each time, React is smart enough that it will only render the new items that are being displayed and leave the others alone. I updated my example to add a `key` to each `li`.

Comment: Check out the docs for a better explanation about keys and multiple renders: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys And https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Chase, a followup question--what would you recommend if notifications is passed in as a prop and doesn't contain a dismissed attribute? I know it's an antipattern to modify props so am wondering what the best practice is in this case.

Comment: @user3802348 I would move the `dismissNotification` function to the parent component that contains the notifications. Or if that's not possible, I would copy props.notifications to state and then use `componentWillReceiveProps` to handle any updates of `this.props.notifications`.